# What is Google Image's id or class that corresponds to the box that lets you drag and drop images?

Tags: python, selenium, google-image-search

I am using Python Selenium to make some sort of Python Console version of Google Images. I already got the part where it opens up and clicks the camera icon. Unfortunately, I don't know what the id or class is for the box that lets you drag in images, as when I try to use an Id from what appears to be the box it says "Element not interactable"
the code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://images.google.com")

print("Googlen't Images")
image_query = input("Enter path where image is: ")

cameraicon = driver.find_element_by_class_name("BwoPOe")
cameraicon.click()
time.sleep(2)
box = driver.find_element_by_id("dRSWfb") #this is the one that gives "element not interactable" error
box.send_keys(image_query)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: error gives line with `send_keys()`, not `find_...` - so your comment in code is misleading.

Problem is that `"dRSWfb` is a `<div>` and you can't send keys to `<div>`. Inside this `<div>` is `<input>` which you should get and send keys.

This `<input>` has id `Ycyxxc`

```
box = driver.find_element_by_id("Ycyxxc")
box.send_keys(image_query)
```

---

I don't know how to drag'n'drop in `Selenium` (if it is even possible) but `DevTools` in `Firefox` shows events `dragover` and `drop` for `<div>` with id `QDMvGf`

---

**EDIT:** to send local file you can use button `Browse` on second tab
instead of `drag'n'drop`

[image]

which you can access using id `awyMjb`

```
box = driver.find_element_by_id("awyMjb")
box.send_keys(image_query)
```

---

Minimal working code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

print("Googlen't Images")
image_query = input("Enter path where image is: ")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
#driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/furas/bin/geckodriver')

driver.get("https://images.google.com")

cameraicon = driver.find_element_by_class_name("BwoPOe")
cameraicon.click()
time.sleep(1)

# send word or url on first tab
#box = driver.find_element_by_id("Ycyxxc")
#box.send_keys(image_query)

# send local file on second tab
box = driver.find_element_by_id("awyMjb")
box.send_keys(image_query)
```